# Ram consumed by single query in Postgres using SqlAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a list of 36 queries ranging from low complexity(No joins) to high complexity(joins with subquery). I want to find the RAM Consumed by each query.

This is required for performance testing for the application which I am building.

Can anyone please help with the same?

I am creating a SQLAlchemy session object and executing raw queries directly.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't make much sense. Queries don't consume memory apart from storing their exact text, since they are simply strings of characters. The Postgres daemon and other related [processes do consume memory](https://www.postgresql.fastware.com/blog/back-to-basics-with-postgresql-memory-components), and a lot of it is shared and cannot be attributed to any one query. Please clarify your ultimate goal.

Comment: @mustaccio: that's not entirely true. A query can absolutely use memory, e.g. to store intermediate results, build hash tables, sort results and so on.

Comment: If the query needs memory, you can see that if you look at the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name may be I'm being too pedantic, but it's a postgres backend process that requests and uses memory, not the query (which still is just a string of characters). The plan will give an indication of how much memory the process might need to allocate for a particular query, but some of it may be shared between different queries executed by the same process.

Comment: @mustaccio Apologies for confusion. Requirement is to get approx RAM usage by postgres daemon and other related process _when a particular query executes_!

Comment: @mustaccio, pedantic translation for you: *"ram consumed by query"*: *"ram consumed by running the query"*.

Comment: Ok, is shared buffers memory "consumed by running a query"? Which one?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on "log_statement_stats", and look at the 'max resident size' line from the log file (or set `client_min_messages TO log;`).

Is is a pretty crummy interface, and the number it gives is the high water mark for the connection, so you would have to run each statement in a separate connection while testing it.